# unable to locate maven clean plugin in my pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am executing maven clean command in parallel mode.

I am getting following warning.

```
[WARNING] The following plugins are not marked @threadSafe in yourwebapp:
[WARNING] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.1.1
[WARNING] org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6
```

I could find `org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6` plugin but unable to find `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin` in my pom.xml.

I know that I need to change the version of these plugin to a threadsafe version. But Unable to locate them.

can some one help where to locate maven clean plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean plugin is configured implicitly in super pom. You can override (redefine)  it in your project pom. Run `mvn help:effective-pom` or `mvn clean:help` to see how clean plugin is currently configured,  or mvn clean:help

Comment: Thank you. But this is my project main pom file.

Comment: while effective-pom will list the versions and lifecycle bindings, most versions arent actually defined in the super pom.

Answer (score 1):

some plugins are bound to the lifecycle by default (differs with project `<packaging>`)
to change the version of the maven clean plugin your project uses simply declare the version you want in `<pluginManagement>`:

```
<build>
   <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
</build>
```